# How do I pass enum parameter values to a RESTful service

Tags: c#, rest

I have a service in the form :

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetProductCode(Products product, SubProducts subProduct)
```

Where the 2 values being passed are an enum value. How should I consume this and how do I get the returned value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following in your WebApiConfig file:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "ProductCodeRoute",
  routeTemplate: "api/YourControllerName/{product}/{subProduct}"
);
```

So that clients can call the service at: `//Url/YourControllerName/1/2` to get the product code.